# What is the size limit of GitHub Page's Photos, Videos and Text files?

Tags: github, github-pages

According to "https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota"
GitHub says 1 GB size for each Repo but it says 100 MB file size for it's GitHub Pages, what does it mean by 100 MB? i mean file in the sense "only text/program files"? or inclding media such photos, video?

Confusing here, please help us

Answer (score 0):

> what does it mean by 100 MB? i mean file in the sense "only text/program files"?

No, all files. HTML, CSS, images, audio, video, anything.